# CASE WHEN expression over multiple columns with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following input columns with data

```
Type1       Time1     Type2    Time2    Type3      Time3
Linehaul    3        Trans      2       Sort       1
Trans       5        Sort       2       Linehaul   2
```

The output should look like this, with a new column at the end that picks the sorting time from the previous columns WHERE type 1 or type 2 or type 3 = Sort
The word Sort can only occur once in ANY of the three previous types.
Code should appear in SQL Oracle

```
Type1       time1    Type2  time2   Type3     time3    Trans time for sort
Linehaul    3        Trans  2       Sort      1         1
Trans       5        Sort   2       Linehaul  2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it pretty simple. e.g.

```
with tab as(
  select 'Linehaul' as c1,   3 as val1,  'Trans'as c2,      2 as val2,       'Sort' as c3,       1 as val3  from dual union all
  select 'Trans',       5,        'Sort',       2 ,      'Linehaul',   2   from dual

)
select t.* 
      ,case 
        when t.c1 = 'Sort' then val1
        when t.c2 = 'Sort' then val2
        when t.c3 = 'Sort' then val3
        else -1
          end as X
from tab t
```